# React.memo with isEqual method from lodash incompatible?

Tags: reactjs, lodash, react-hooks

I'm trying to convert my components to be used with React.memo.
the problem that some of my components has object or array props which I would like to deeply compare.

Looking at react docs for memo, I can pass a function to do the comparing.

I have provided it with lodash isEqual deep comparison method and it didnt work sometimes.

I think there is some issue with isEqual when it tries to compare a react component with children prop inside.

Example of React children structure:
[image: example]

Running lodash isEqual between two children objects returns false even if they are completely the same.

I would like to find a way to keep using lodash isEqual as it is working great with any other type of structure, but maybe modify it to work with childrens too.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!!!

PS - Im running the lodash method like this:

```
const component = React.memo((props) => {
...code here with children usage..
}, (oldProps, newProps) => _.isEqual(oldProps, newProps)
```

Comment: It's a react concept - https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren

Comment: Remember that the childNodes are not specifically props. So it is not about lodash isEqual comparison, it is more about the callback of React.memo. Do you have the child object there?.

Comment: Did you ever solve this @Kiper. I am running into the same issue. Seemingly equal arrays with objects returns false

Answer (score 0):

You have function onClick prop, isEqual can not check did function changed or not, thats why it returns false.